# Image is not storing in the database Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

The image is not storing in the database

I already tried looking at other possible solutions but nothing work I also tried with using `guessextension`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $student = new student();

        $this->validateRequest();

        $student->name = $request->name;
        $student->address = $request->address;

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename=time() .'.'. $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/student/',$filename);
        $student->image = $filename;                   
    }   
    else  {
            return $request;
            $student->image ='';
    } 

     $student->save();

    return redirect()->route('show')->with('response', 'Registered Successfully');
}
```

> Here is the form

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<form method="get" action="/student" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="email">    
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="email">
  </div>

  <div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" >
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</div>

@stop
```

What I need is the image to be stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

actually, when you upload an image to the server you save only the path of the image into your database

so firstly you need to Create a symbolic link from `"public/storage"` to

```
"storage/app/public"
```

by artisan command: `php artisan storage:link`

after that, you can optimize this part of your code from this

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename=time() .'.'. $extension;
    $file->move('uploads/student/',$filename);
    $student->image = $filename;                   
}
```

to this simple one

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->image->store('uploads');                   
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `php artisan storage:link`? The full command is preferable.